# Combo de comunidades autonomas y otro de provincias con dependencia con jquery. Cómo seleccionar varios options del select para incluir datos en estos

Tags: jquery

estoy desarrollando un formulario que incluye un select con las comunidades autonomas y otro que deberá incluir las provincias segun la comunidad seleccionada.

Resultado esperado:

o   El select de la comunidad autónoma debe contener la lista de comunidades autónomas, y muestra la opción de Selecciona.

o   El select de la provincia sólo contiene la opción “Selecciona una comunidad autónoma”

-En el momento en que alguien selecciona una comunidad autónoma, el select de provincia se carga con las provincias correspondientes a esa comunidad autónoma.

o   Si hay varias provincias pertenecientes a esa comunidad autónoma, el select tiene que tener seleccionada la opción de “Selecciona una provincia”.

o   Si la comunidad autónoma sólo cuenta con una provincia el select se cargará únicamente con esa provincia que será la que está seleccionada.

o En el momento en que el select de la comunidad autónoma tiene como valor seleccionado “Selecciona”:
El select de provincia se debe vaciar y sólo contener la opción de “Selecciona una comunidad autónoma”

He conseguido todos los puntos menos el que al seleccionar una comunidad que tenga más de una provincia aparezca la opción selecciona una provincia. No logro acceder a los option value que cumplen esos requisitos para añadir en el select la parte de selecciona una provincia.

Adjunto el código y la parte que he intentado pero no ha funcionado.
Gracias de antemano.

---

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <br>
                <label for="comunidadAutonoma" class="form-label">Comunidad Autónoma</label>
                <select id="input" class="form-control">                    
                    <option value="0" selected>Selecciona</option>
                    <option value="1">Andalucía</option>
                    <option value="2">Aragón</option>
                    <option value="3">Asturias, Principado de</option>
                    <option value="4">Balears, Illes</option>
                    <option value="5">Canarias</option>
                    <option value="6">Cantabria</option>
                    <option value="7">Castilla y León</option>
                    <option value="8">Castilla - La Mancha</option>
                    <option value="9">Cataluña</option>
                    <option value="10">Comunitat Valenciana</option>
                    <option value="11">Extremadura</option>
                    <option value="12">Galicia</option>
                    <option value="13">Madrid, Comunidad de</option>
                    <option value="14">Murcia, Región de</option>
                    <option value="15">Navarra, Comunidad Foral de</option>
                    <option value="16">País Vasco</option>
                    <option value="17">Rioja, La</option>
                    <option value="18">Ceuta</option>
                    <option value="19">Melilla</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <br>
                <label for="provincia" class="form-label">Provincia</label>
                <select id="output" class="form-control">
                    <option selected>Selecciona una comunidad autónoma</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

---

index.js

```
var options = {
    0: ["Selecciona una comunidad autónoma"],
    1: ["Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", "Huelva", "Jaén", "Málaga", "Sevilla"],
    2: ["Huesca", "Teruel", "Zaragoza"],
    3: ["Asturias"],
    4: ["Balears, Illes"],
    5: ["Palmas, Las", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife"],
    6: ["Cantabria"],
    7: ["Ávila", "Burgos", "León", "Palencia", "Salamanca", "Segovia", "Soria", "Valladolid", "Zamora"],
    8: ["Albacete", "Ciudad Real", "Cuenca", "Guadalajara", "Toledo"],
    9: ["Barcelona", "Girona", "Lleida", "Tarragona"],
    10: ["Alicante / Alacant", "Castellón / Castelló", "Valencia / València"],
    11: ["Badajoz", "Cáceres"],
    12: ["Coruña, A", "Lugo", "Ourense", "Pontevedra"],
    13: ["Madrid"],
    14: ["Murcia"],
    15: ["Navarra"],
    16: ["Araba/Álava", "Gipuzkoa", "Bizkaia"],
    17: ["Rioja, La"],
    18: ["Ceuta"],
    19: ["Melilla"]
}

if ($("#input option[value='0']").attr("selected", true) || $("#input option[value='3']").attr("selected", true)){
    $(function () {
        var rellenarOutput = function () {
            var selected = $('#input').val();
            $('#output').empty();
            $('#output').html("<option>" + "Selecciona una provincia" + "</option>");
            options[selected].forEach(function (element, index) {
                $('#output').append('<option value="' + element + '">' + element + '</option>');
            });
        }
        $('#input').change(rellenarOutput);
        rellenarOutput();
    });
}
else {
    $(function () {
        var rellenarOutput = function () {
            var selected = $('#input').val();
            $('#output').empty();
            options[selected].forEach(function (element, index) {
                $('#output').append('<option value="' + element + '">' + element + '</option>');
            });
        }
        $('#input').change(rellenarOutput);
        rellenarOutput();
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar opciones de distintos select con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370138/eliminar-opciones-de-distintos-select-con-javascript)