# Como rellenar un tercer select, despues de cambiar 2 selects

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Contexto; estoy haciendo un buscador (adentro de un CRUD en wordpress) con dos condiciones en el SQL que el pueblo y la especialidad me filtren los clientes que tengan ese mismo pueblo y especialidad.

SQL:

```
 $pueblos = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_GET['pueblo']);
    
    $servicios = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_GET['servicio']);
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wpr4_administradormapa` WHERE localidades LIKE '%".$pueblos."%' AND servicio LIKE '%".$servicios."%';";
```

¿Se puede hacer de una forma dinámica (sin el submit) que no recarge la pagina y al cambiar cada select vaya cambiando la variable en el SQL?

```
<div class='contenedorEstilos'>
 <hr/>
    <h4 class='titulosEstilos'>Búsqueda por Pueblo y Especialidad</h4>
        <form action='#' method='GET'>
        <select name='pueblo' class='selectEstilos'>
            <option>Seleccione el pueblo</option>
            <option value='Pueblo 1'>Pueblo 1</option>
            <option value='Pueblo 2'>Pueblo 2</option>
            <option value='Pueblo 3'>Pueblo 3</option>
        </select>

        <select name='servicio' class='selectEstilos'>
            <option>Seleccione la especialidad</option>
            <option value='neuro'>Neurología</option>
            <option value='psico'>Psicología</option>
            <option value='pedia'>Pediatría</option>
        </select>
        

    </form>
</div>
```

php:

```
include 'conexion.php'

$pueblos = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_GET['pueblo']);
    
$servicios = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_GET['servicio']);
    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wpr4_administradormapa` WHERE localidades LIKE '%".$pueblos."%' AND servicio LIKE '%".$servicios."%';";
    
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
     
if($result){
   echo "<select  onchange='location = this.value' class='selectEstilos'>
<option selected>Escoja cliente</option>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    echo "<option value=?id".$row['id'].">".$row['nombre']."</option>";
}

echo "</select></div>";
} else {
 echo "no funciona";
}
```

Explicación del funcionamiento: se escogen los 2 select y se rellena el tercero, me imagino implementando Ajax y no tengo mucho conocimiento en esto, si me podrían guiar seria de ayuda, gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar opciones de distintos select con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370138/eliminar-opciones-de-distintos-select-con-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede implementar con Ajax para evitar la recarga de la página y JQuery para acceder a los elementos del DOM, esto haciendo peticiones Ajax si es que los **select** se actualizan con datos de la BD, ejemplo:

```js
//FUNCION QUE SE EJECUTA AL TERMINAR DE CARGAR EL DOM
$(document).ready(function() {

  //DETECTAMOS CAMBIOS EN EL SELECT DE SERVICIO
  $("#servicio").on('change', function() {
  //TOMAMOS EL VALUE SELECCIONADO DE LOS DOS PRIMEROS SELECT
    var pueblo = $("#pueblo option:selected").val();
    var servicio = $("#servicio option:selected").val();

    //console.log(pueblo);
    //console.log(servicio);

    //ENVIAMOS LOS DOS VALUE POR AJAX METODO POST PARA PINTAR TERCER SELECT RESULTADO
    $.post("bd.php", {
      pueblo: pueblo,
      servicio: servicio
    }, function(data) {
      //PINTAMOS LA DATA DE LA CONSULTA EN EL TERCER SELECT
      $("#resultado").html(data);
    });

  })
});
```

**CON ESTA FUNCIÓN DE JQUERY ENVIAMOS LOS DOS VALORES DE LOS DOS PRIMEROS SELECT A PHP, EL RESULTADO DE TU CONSULTA LO PINTARA EN TU TERCER SELECT, YO LE PUSE RESULTADO, CÁMBIALE EL NOMBRE**.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pueblo']) && isset($_POST['servicio'])){
    $pueblo = $_POST['pueblo'];
    $servicio = $_POST['servicio'];

    //AQUI TU CONSULTA
    echo '<option>'.$pueblo.$servicio.'</option>';
}else {
    echo '<option>FALLO</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Digamos si necesito combinar la data del primer select, con el segundo select para pintar en un tercer select, adonde se pondria un AND?, o tendria que poner la funcion del segundo select debajo del " $("#pueblo").change(function() {", gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: No entiendo tu duda, se supone que seleccionas el **primer select** y este pinta el segundo, al seleccionar el **segundo select** pintaría el tercero no?, o como?, se supone que esa es la lógica correcta.

Comment: se seleccionan los dos select, el primero cambia la primera variable en la consulta sql -> pueblos y el segundo select cambia la segunda variable -> servicios, al cambiar los dos, se pintan en el tercero que es el bucle que cree en el archivo php

Comment: Por lo que entiendo necesitas enviar el valor del primer y segundo **select** juntos para pintar el tercero?

Comment: sipe, entre los dos selects cambian una consulta y está se pinte en el tercero (:

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta a lo que comentaste que querías, dime si era eso.

Comment: si men, muchas gracias, es la solución a mi problema, éxitos! (: