# Selects dependientes de 3 niveles no funcionan

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando realizar un select dinámico Departamento->Municipio->Localidad. Con este código me funciona bien solo 2 selects, llega la información desde la base de datos. El problema está cuando quiero añadir un select a partir del segundo, ahí ya no funciona. Es como si no cargaran los datos a enviar por ajax del segundo select, así que en el tercero no aparece absolutamente nada.

He revisado varias veces y buscado otras alternativas, pero sigue sin funcionar y la verdad no sé que está mal.

Les comparto el código de lo que tengo.

ajaxData

```
<?php 

include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
 
if(!empty($_POST["departamento_id"])){ 
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE departamento_id = ".$_POST['departamento_id']; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
     
   
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['municipio_id'].'">'.$row['municipio'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Departamento no disponible</option>'; 
    } 
}elseif(!empty($_POST["municipio_id"])){ 
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM localidades WHERE municipio_id = ".$_POST['municipio_id']; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
     
    
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_localidad'].'">'.$row['nombre_localidad'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Localidad no disponible</option>'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

index

```
   <?php         
    include_once 'dbConfig.php';                  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM departamentos"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#departamento').on('change', function dep(){
        var departamentoID = $(this).val();
        if(departamentoID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'departamento_id='+departamentoID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#municipio').html(html);
                    $('#localidad').html('<option value="">Seleccione Departamento primero</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#municipio').html('<option value="">Seleccione Departamento primero</option>');
            $('#localidad').html('<option value="">Seleccione Municipio primero</option>'); 
        }
    });
    
    $('#municipio').on('change', function loc(){
        var localidadID = $(this).val();
        if(localidadID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'municipio_id='+localidadID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#localidad').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('localidad').html('<option value="">Seleccione municipio primero</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>    
<!-- Departamento dropdown -->
<select id="departamento">
    <option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_departamento'].'">'.$row['departamento'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Departamento no disponible</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>    
<!-- Municipio dropdown -->
<select id="municipio">
    <option value="">Seleccione Departamento primero</option>
</select>  
<!-- Localidad dropdown -->
<select id="localidad">
    <option value="">Seleccione Municipio primero</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has depurado? Si he entendido bien, este es el bloque que no funciona: `$('#municipio').on('change', function loc(){` intenta poner un alert, luego de haber definido esto: `var localidadID = $(this).val();` coloca: `alert(localidadID);` y dinos si ves el valor correcto de la localidad. Si lo ves, entonces, hay que pasar a depurar en el servidor.

Comment: Ya verifique, pero solo muestra un alert vacio

Comment: Supongo que el `alert` lo pusiste **justo debajo** de esta línea: `var localidadID = $(this).val();` Por cierto, el `loc()` no tiene sentido ahí, basta con ponerlo así: `$('#municipio').on('change', function (){` Revisa [la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/change/) y los ejemplos de código allí.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar opciones de distintos select con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370138/eliminar-opciones-de-distintos-select-con-javascript)